# Issues with setTimeout when having multiple copies of the same component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux, settimeout

I've tried to debug this issue for hours but I can't seem to fix it for the life of me. I'm trying to create a toast component which displays itself inside of a list whenever a toast is created. It works fine until I tried to implement a system which removes the toast from the list after 3 seconds.

```
const Toast = (props) => {
    const [active, setActive] = useState(false)
    const { removeToast } = useToast()

    const timerRef = useRef(null)
    const timer2Ref = useRef(null)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (active) return; // attempt to prevent multiple timers from being created

        setActive(true)

        timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
            setActive(false)

            timer2Ref.current = setTimeout(() => { // Second timeout to remove the toast from the DOM after transition has finished
                removeToast(props.id)
            }, 300)

        }, 3000)

        return () => {
            // If clear, it prevents the last toast in the list from being removed?
            // If not cleared, strictmode causes issues (performs as expected with strictmode off)
            clearTimeout(timer2Ref.current)
            clearTimeout(timerRef.current)
        }
    }, [])

    return (
        <div className={`p-4  h-14 rounded-lg w-80 transition-all duration-300 flex-auto flex-0 ${props.className}`}
        /*${active ? 'translate-y-0' : 'translate-y-96'} Removed to recognise issue more clearly */ 
        >
            {props.message}
        </div>
    )
}

export default Toast
```

It doesn't seem to behave as expected regardless of what I do. If I clear the timeout, it works as expected but the last toast that is in the list never get's removed.

And if I don't clear the timeout (which I believe you should in order to prevent memory leaks), all of the toasts get deleted at seemingly the same time which what I assume is because of StrictMode, as with StrictMode disabled it all functions as expected. But I'd prefer to not remove StrictMode just for this.

Here's the list component as well (I don't believe that's where the issue is)

```
const ToastList = () => {
    const toastList = useSelector(state => state.toast.value)

    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(toastList)
    }, [toastList])

    if (toastList.length > 0) {
        return (
            <div className="flex flex-col-reverse pointer-events-none w-full z-50 fixed bottom-0 ">
                {toastList.map((toast, index) => (
                    <Toast message={toast.message } icon={toast.icon} key={index} id={toast.id} className={`mx-auto my-3 ${toast.color}`} />
                ))}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ToastList
```

*Not sure if it's relevant, but I'm storing all the toasts in an array through Redux.

--

I've looked around on here and found another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59210403/useeffect-hook-misbehaves-with-settimeout-and-state) that looked like the OP had a similar issue. So I tried to use the removeToast function through a ref as seen in the post, but that didn't solve it.

I've also tried to use a custom [useTimeout](https://usehooks-ts.com/react-hook/use-timeout) hook but that also didn't fix it.

I'm out of ideas myself, so any help would be appreciated :)
Also I'm not too experienced with react so I apologise if the issue observed here is a result of my lack of knowledge haha, and if you can see any bad practices here just let me know so I don't make those mistakes in the future

Comment: The only overt issue I see is the use of the array index as the React key when mapping toasts. Think you could create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of this code that reproduces the issue that we could inspect live?

Comment: Sure @DrewReese, I haven't used codesandbox before, but I've created a live sandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/live/f34d1a7da5a). Is that what you mean?

Comment: I wasn't able to fork your sandbox and get it to run, but I was able to copy the code into a vanilla React [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/issues-with-settimeout-when-having-multiple-copies-of-the-same-component-73cebd) and tweak a few things. I don't know if my tweaks would resolve the issues in your sandbox, or if the issues are related to the Vite setup or tailwind.

Comment: @DrewReese Alright, I've just gone through your sandbox and my app, and slowly made any changes on my app that you had in the sandbox in order to find what resolved it. I was able to get everything working by applying the key prop change in the list component, and enabling the clearing of the timeouts. So it looks like the initial suggestion you made along with turning clearing back on fixed the issue. Im new to stack overflow, but I assume you need to create an answer which I can mark as resolved? If you could do that outlining those changes for other people that would be great, thanks heaps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only overt issue I see in your code is using the `toastList` array index as the React key. Using the array index as a key is generally considered an anti-pattern in React, the accepted exception being when the array isn't ever mutated. This is clearly an issue in your code though since toast messages can be added and removed to the `toastList` at any time. The mapped `toast.id` is the best option for a React key since it is an intrinsic property that uniquely identifies a toast message.

ToastList.jsx

```
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Toast from "./Toast";

const ToastList = () => {
  const toastList = useSelector((state) => state.toast.value);

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col-reverse pointer-events-none w-full z-50 fixed bottom-0 ">
      {toastList.map((toast) => (
        <Toast
          key={toast.id} // <-- use id as key
          className={`mx-auto my-3 ${toast.color}`}
          {...toast}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `Toast` component ***should*** clear any running timeouts in the case that the component is prematurely unmounted prior to the timeouts expiring. Split the logic of enqueueing the timeouts into one `useEffect` hook with appropriate dependencies and the cleanup function to clear the timeout on the occasion the component unmounts.

```
import { useRef } from "react";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import useToast from "../hooks/useToast";

const Toast = (props) => {
  const [active, setActive] = useState(false);
  const { removeToast } = useToast();

  const timerRef = useRef(null);
  const timer2Ref = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Only instantiate timers when toast inactive
    if (!active) {
      setActive(true);

      timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        timer2Ref.current = setTimeout(() => {
          setActive(false);
          // Second timeout to remove it from the DOM after transition has finished
          removeToast(props.id);
        }, 300);
      }, 3000);
    }
  }, [active, props, removeToast]);

  // Mounting useEffect hook to return unmounting cleanup function.
  useEffect(
    () => () => {
      clearTimeout(timer2Ref.current);
      clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
    },
    []
  );

  return (
    <div
      className={`p-4 h-14 rounded-lg transition-all duration-300 flex flex-row text-slate-100 w-80 ${props.className}`}
      /*${active ? 'translate-y-0' : 'translate-y-96'} Removed to recognise issue more clearly */
    >
      {props.message}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Toast;
```

Demo

[image: Edit issues-with-settimeout-when-having-multiple-copies-of-the-same-component]